# Iterating vertical values in a collection to horizontal values in another collection

Tags: java, string, list

I have List of String with some Strings in my java program as below:

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

    input.add("2013-07-31,A,47");
    input.add("2013-06-28,A,52");
    input.add("2013-05-31,A,63");

    input.add("2013-07-31,B,47");
    input.add("2013-06-28,B,54");
    input.add("2013-05-31,B,91");

    input.add("2013-07-31,C,78");
    input.add("2013-06-28,C,24");

    input.add("2013-07-31,D,99");
    input.add("2013-05-31,D,82");
```

Here in each string, the comma separated first token represents the date, second token is the product name while third token is the price.

I want to produce an excel report with below table format using above list:

```
Prod   |           Price
---------------------------------------------
  XXX    |   M1        M2        M3
---------------------------------------------
  A      |   47        52        63
  B      |   47        54        91
  C      |   78        24        00
  D      |   99        00        82
---------------------------------------------
```

Where M1 is 2013-07-31, M2 is 2013-06-28 while M3 is 2013-05-31.

To achieve this my output collection should be a List of String with member Strings as below:

```
  A, 47, 52, 63
  B, 47, 54, 91
  C, 78, 24, 00
  D, 99, 00, 82
```

Note that in the input Strings where there are no value present for a date, for e.g. 2013-05-31 for product C and 2013-06-28 for product D, the value should be defaulted to 00 in the output Strings.

Thus, in the output strings such absent values are taken as 00.

How to iterate my input collection which has datewise vertical values for product to get the  output collection which is product wise horizontal values for the 3 dates ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: split the string and creat product objects, that would be much easier.

Comment: @peeskillet: Creating iterator for the first String.. :) should I paste that ? This is not a homework question...

Comment: Do you want to omit the dates completely from the new list?

Comment: @peeskillet: Yes. The input list maintains the order with highest date first. I have been able to get the input in such manner. So we can comfortably assume that in the output String, first value is first date and so on. But while creation, we have to see that if a date is absent, the value should be taken as 00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You can easily adapt it further to match your exact needs.

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.List;


    public class Test002 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

            input.add("2013-07-31,A,47");
            input.add("2013-06-28,A,52");
            input.add("2013-05-31,A,63");

            input.add("2013-07-31,B,47");
            input.add("2013-06-28,B,54");
            input.add("2013-05-31,B,91");

            input.add("2013-07-31,C,78");
            input.add("2013-06-28,C,24");

            input.add("2013-07-31,D,99");
            input.add("2013-05-31,D,82");

            HashSet<Date> dates = new HashSet<Date>();
            HashSet<String> products = new HashSet<String>();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            for (String s : input){
                String[] str = s.split(",");
                dates.add(sdf.parse(str[0]));
                products.add(str[1]);
                counts.put(str[0] + "#" + str[1], Integer.parseInt(str[2]));
            }

            for (String p : products){
                for (Date dt : dates){
                    Integer cnt = counts.get(sdf.format(dt) + "#" + p);
                    if (cnt == null){
                        System.out.print("00 ");
                    }else{
                        System.out.printf("%2d ", cnt);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: +1 for counts.put(str[0] + "#" + str[1], Integer.parseInt(str[2]));
 this line... saved the day! :)

Comment: @Vicky Just a trivial separator trick as you won't have # anywhere else in your program's calculations. So I put it there just to avoid any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I think a list is the right data structure to store your values because it's flat. We don't know very much about your domain, but if more than three dates are allowed, you may end up with a sheet with a zillion columns.

In fact, if that's a time series, a series of sheets is the best representation, and maybe a sheet with aggregation periods (quarters, weeks, months) and averages. So I'd model your domain as follows:

```
class TimeSeries {
  String itemDescription;
  Collection<Sample> samples;
}

class Sample {
  Date date;
  BigInteger price;
}
```

Then I'd convert your input list of strings to a list of `TimeSeries` objects, that you will subsequently aggregate by date, possibly making an average when multiple samples are available for the same period, and skipping empty ones. And finally draw the digested result onto the Excel sheet.

Comment: Nopes. Dates will be either 3 or less.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It give you the desired output first using a map then converting back to a list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

        input.add("2013-07-31,A,47");
        input.add("2013-06-28,A,52");
        input.add("2013-05-31,A,63");

        input.add("2013-07-31,B,47");
        input.add("2013-06-28,B,54");
        input.add("2013-05-31,B,91");

        input.add("2013-07-31,C,78");
        input.add("2013-06-28,C,24");

        input.add("2013-07-31,D,99");
        input.add("2013-05-31,D,82");

        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

        for (String s : input) {
            String[] tokens = s.split(",");
            if (!map.containsKey(tokens[1])) {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(tokens[2]);
                map.put(tokens[1], list);
            } else {
                ArrayList<String> list = map.get(tokens[1]);
                list.add(tokens[2]);
                map.put(tokens[1], list);
            }
        }

        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(entry.getKey() + ",");
            for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
                sb.append(s + ",");
            }
            newList.add(sb.toString());
        }

        Collections.sort(newList);

        for (String s : newList) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
A,47,52,63,
B,47,54,91,
C,78,24,
D,99,82,
```

Sorry, I just notices your NOTE, but I wasn't really able to understand what you meant by it, so I'm not really sure about how to go about producing the zeroes

Comment: In the else part `map.put(tokens[1], list);` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it under the assumptions that

- at most one sample per date is allowed
- your rendering code decides what dates to pick

This approach doesn't build an intermediate data structure before rendering, but draws the cells immediately when they are read from the input list:

```java
// Maps items IDs to the row index in the excel sheet
Map<String, Integer> items = new HashMap<>();
// Maps the string representation of the date to the column index in the sheet
Map<String, Integer> columns = new HashMap<>();

public void process(List<String> input) {
  for (String line: input) {
    String[] desc = input.split(",");
    Integer rowIdx = items.get(desc[1]);
    if (rowIdx == null) {
      rowIdx = drawNewItemAndGetRowIndex(desc[1]);
    }
    drawPrice(rowIdx, columns.get(desc[0]), desc[2]);
  }
}
```

Before running this code you need to initialize the Excel sheet and the `columns` map by putting the dates you are interested in. Note I used the string representation of the dates instead of actual `Date` objects because the parsing is not needed for your purposes.

I left the implementation of `drawNewItemAndGetRowIndex` to you, but it basically creates a new rows in the Excel sheet, register the index in the `items` map, draws the item caption and returns the row index.